# how to send common request for the multiple tabs?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am developing one timer in web application. in this timer i am sending update request at every 2 minutes to update the time in server. now problem is that when multiple tabs are open in browser with this application then at 2 minutes every tabs will send request for update time. so the traffic is increase.I want to send one common request from every tabs how it is possible? I Have tried ajax for that.

i am using java for the web development.

Comment: manage at server by identifying the browser by cookie, and make sure one update is taken at time for cookie

Comment: Thank you so much for response ,I am beginner in this can you explain in detail?

Comment: Create one common tab, which is accessible/viewable from all tabs..

Comment: @Java Learner how is this possible have you any reference or links then please send.

Comment: Stack Overflow site itself is an example, where we get notification when points are earned..and visible from all tabs..

Comment: @javaLearner : is this push notification on SO?

Comment: Not necessarily a Push notification in your case..You have already done it for a single tab I guess, make same coding for the common tab..

Comment: then how can i implements this? is there any framework for this?

Comment: @ Java Learner : he does not have common code but he has same code(same page) open in mutiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can not control the behavior of the browser, but one thing that you can do to minimize the processing .for that implement a filter that will filter all the request, and in that if you get a request for updating the time you update the time and put that information in the session, as because all the tabs will share only one session, for the next request you can check when was the last time you updated the time by retrieving the object from the session if the last update time is less then say 2 min, then you can just discard the request.

I hope this approach will help

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to decrease traffic on server. if i compare all those things on the server means i have to send request on server and traffic remain same.My main requirement is to decrease the traffic.